# Unable to access asp.net website after setting asp.net version to 2.0 in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, asp.net-2.0

I have an asp.net website that has been running well in IIS 6.0. I very well remember the sites ASP.NET version was set to version 2.0 in IIS but i just checked and found the version set to nothing. If i click the site asp.net version dropdownlist in IIS, i can see two options(1.1.4322 and 2.0.50727).

The problem is i set it back to 2.0 and now the site can nolonger be accessed both remotely and locally.

And i cant set it back to "nothing" since the version dropdownlist only has two options( 2.0.50727 and 1.1.4322).

Any ideas what could be going wrong.

**Below is what i get in the browser**

> The page cannot be found The page you
>   are looking for might have been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.
>
> Please try the following:
>
> •Make surethat the Web site address displayed in
>   the address bar of your browser is
>   spelled and formatted correctly.
>
> • If
>   you reached this page by clicking a
>   link, contact the Web site
>   administrator to alert them that the
>   link is incorrectly formatted.
>
> •Click the Back button to try another
>   link.  HTTP Error 404 - File or
>   directory not found. Internet
>   Information Services (IIS)
>
> Technical Information (for support
>   personnel) •
>
> Go to Microsoft Product
>   Support Services and perform a title
>   search for the words HTTP and 404. 
>   • Open IIS Help, which is accessible
>   in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search
>   for topics titled Web Site Setup,
>   Common Administrative Tasks, and About
>   Custom Error Messages.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET your website is running? If it's below .net 2.0 then you should select 1.1.4322, any framework version above and including 2.0 select box should be 2.0.50727.

Comment: Make sure that asp.net isapi is enabled and allowed.

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: I have edited the post to include the message i get in the browser.

Its been working all along, and suddenly thats what i get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the culprit

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2010/06/14/iis-6-applications-may-stop-responding-after-you-install-microsoft-update-kb-982666.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/webtopics/iis-6-applications-may-stop-responding-after-you-install-microsoft-update-kb-982666)

​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like .NET isn't properly installed on your IIS website.

Try to open a command prompt, step into %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ and run aspnet_regiis.exe (use the directive -? for help). If you only run one IIS website on your server you can run aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

.net 1.1 and .net 2.0 don't get along well on IIS 6.0. You must run one of the frameworks in a different app pool - so, for every 1.1 website, for example, run it in a new app pool (other than the default).

Comment: In this particular case, all sites on server are running under 2.0